# Migration from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2019 : issue using EncryptByPassPhrase

Tags: sql, sql-server

After the SQL team migrated the server from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2019 UC8, an issue started to occur. The issue is during user maintenance. Basically when the password is being inserted or saved. There is a stored procedure that contains the following:

```
UPDATE TableOfCreds
SET Password = EncryptByPassPhrase('ThisPassword', @Password)
WHERE User_ID = @UserID
```

The insert is the same for the password. In SQL Server 2012 it functions as expected, in SQL Server 2019 the following error occurs:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 30, Line 7
> String or binary data would be truncated

On the Microsoft site, it states that SQL Server 2017 onward uses AES256 key and the passphrase is using TRIPLE DES with 128 key bit length. Not sure if this is the cause and if so how to fix it. Some other details are

- Password column in table is of type `varchar(50)`
- Decryption seems to work as expected

Executing the above script outside the procedure results in the same error.

Also some research revealed issues with inlining in UDF's however we are not using functions and converting the procedures to functions may take longer than we want.

What is the best way to encrypt the string and save to the table without receiving the error?

Comment: return type varchar 8000, from doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbypassphrase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

return type varchar 8000

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbypassphrase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

```
select len(EncryptByPassPhrase('ThisPassword','Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.'))
```

### Returns

612

Comment: Does that mean in SQL 2012 varchar(50) was suitable but in 2019 columns would need to be increased to varchar(8000)? The limit being put on the user is 20 characters. Would using the above with a 20 character string give me the number to increase the column size on all tables which contain the passwords? Also is there anything special that needs to be done to preserve the passwords when upsizing the column?

Comment: I can't access SQL 2012 docs online to confirm. The issue here is that you can't decrypt the values stored in the previous version. Can you confirm that? This is a bigger issue than the trivial upsizing.

Comment: Newer SQL version (2022) *can* decrypt key generated by older version (2016). So the "only" thing you need to do is expand the column size. But in general, i would advice not using SQL built-in encryption, because it's not strong enough. Also, you should probably not use reversable passwords but rather hashes

Comment: @Horaciux the issue is not the decryption. This was noted in the original post but removed, for some unknown reason by marc_s. The main issue is encrypting and saving the password to the table. The error of truncation is hampering the attempt to save the password. The main problem I see with upsizing the column is downtime but if needed will take that route. Just want to make sure that the column should be varchar 8000 or to be save maybe using MAX or even converting to varbinary.

Comment: @siggemannen I agree with you regarding the encryption weakness but the call is management's decision to fix this first as it is an immediate issue. Then we will proceed with implementing stronger password methodologies. The decryption does work in 2019 successfully as well. The issue is with the saving of the encrypted data due to the error of data will be truncated.